# Typedef/Global structure in C, without using "typedef"?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, global-variables, typedef

Language: C

I wish I knew how to reference this in the title better. I recently came across this piece of code concerning struct definition, and I am unfamiliar with the syntax, particularly the "*Node" portion. Might someone please help me understand what's going on? Why/how aren't we using typedef/ is this something else entirely? For further reference, the source code uses "Node" (no *asterisk) within some function definitions without passing or declaring any "Node" variables within the function itself. This leads me to think it's some sort of global variable declaration. Any help appreciated!

```
struct node {
    char word[MAX];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} *Node;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `struct` declaration, the right brace that terminates the list of **members may be followed by list of variables**. So, here

```
struct node {
    char word[MAX];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} *Node;
```

`Node` is of type `struct node *` which can hold pointer of any `struct node` type variable. That means, if you have

```
struct node anode;
```

you can do

```
Node = &anode;
```

If you have this kind of global `struct` declaration followed by variables after right brace, that terminates the list of members, then all those variable are global variables of that `struct` type. That means, if you have

```
struct node {
    char word[MAX];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} Node, *ptrNode;
```

and this `struct node` type defined globally then both `Node` and `ptrNode` are global variables.

Don't confuse this with `typedef`. `typedef` is used to create an alias name for another data type.

For e.g.

```
tyepdef struct node {
    char word[MAX];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} stNode, *ptrStNode;
```

Now the `stNode` is an alias of `struct node` and `ptrStNode` is alias of `struct node *`. That means, you can use them to declare variables of `struct node` and `struct node*` type respectively.

For `struct node` type, this

```
stNode aNode;
```

is same as

```
struct node aNode;
```

and for `struct node *` type, this

```
ptrStNode ptrNode;
```

is same as

```
stNode *ptrNode;
```

is same as

```
struct node *ptrNode;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Code defines a pointer name `Node` to a `struct`.  See [declare Node as pointer to struct node](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+node+*Node%3B);

Perhaps it is more understandable broken down into two step equivalent code.

```
  // Define `struct node`
  struct node {
      char word[MAX];
      struct node *left;
      struct node *right;
  };

  // Define & declare a pointer: `Node`
  struct node *Node;
```

---

> Why/how aren't we using typedef/ is this something else entirely?

Author did not want to define an alias for the type `struct main` via `typeface`.  Just to define a type called `struct main` and declare a pointer.

Comment: So it is indeed just syntax for variable declaration and a global one at that?

Comment: @KRKClutch "... and a global one at that"  If code was not in a function, then yes, a global object call `Node`.

Comment: But the author *does* define a type, and a reusable one at that.  The OP seems think that doing so requires use of `typedef`, but of course that's not the case.  `struct node` is a perfectly good type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes that was not worded well as the type `struct main` is defined`.  Answer amended.